# Master Table Products Show with Child Favorite's Check that is product is list in favourite or not in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have question that How can I check using Laravel Query in Product Display Controller that the display product is listed in Favourite table.

My Database Structure is

1. Favourite Table
   -- productid -- customer id
2. Product Table
   -- productid -- productname
3. Customer Table
   -- Customer ID -- Customer Name

I need a query to show all products with favourite icon display on every product, if the customer added in favourite list the favourite icon will be red

I made conditions in view page inside loop but is it possible to check in query and display with column name isFavourite?

like

```blade
@foreach(productsDB as productsRow)
    @if (productsRow == FavouriteRow)
        <i class="favourite-red">icon-heart</i>
    @else
        <i class="favourite-white">icon-heart</i>
    @endif
@endfor
```

Comment: Show your controller method and relations on your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are model relations:

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function favourites() {
        return $this->hasMany(Favourite::class, 'productid');
    }
}

class Favourite extends Model {
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'productid');
    }

    public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customerid');
    }
}
```

This is the query:

```
$customer = Auth::user();

$products = Product::select('products.*')
    ->leftJoin('favourites', function($join) use ($customer) {
        $join->on('products.productid', '=', 'favourites.productid')
            ->where('favourites.customerid', '=', $customer->id);
    })
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('CASE WHEN favourites.productid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isFavourite'))
    ->get();
```

in your blade you can write simply:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @if ($product->isFavourite)
        <i class="favourite-red">icon-heart</i>
    @else
        <i class="favourite-white">icon-heart</i>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

This logic will make your blade file cleaner.

Comment: great, very simple & organize solution, many many thanks